# jQuery: Load body of page into variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm using jQuery to load the result of a PHP script into a variable. The script is passed something that the user typed with a GET request. I want to take just what the script spit out into its `<body>` tag. Here's what I've tried:

**JS:**

```
function loader() {
    var typed = $('#i').val(); //get what user typed in
    $.get("script.php", {i: typed}, function(loaded) {dataloaded = loaded;});
    alert($(dataloaded).find('body'))
}
```

But it just displays `[Objec object]`. How can I get a useful value that is just the contents of the body of a loaded page?

I know the PHP works, I just need the JS.
The script `echo`s something like `1!!2` (two numbers separated by two exclamation points).

**Thanks!**

Comment: what's the value of dataloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the page that I'm trying to fetch to XML. I'm using `$.find` to get each element of interest individually from the XML page, which suits this particular app well.

This problem has disappeared, as there is no longer a `head` section to ignore, and I'm just grabbing individual XML elements anyway.

Thanks for all your time and help!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the `dataloaded` which might not be assigned due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX calls. The only safe place to access it is inside the success callback. Also you could use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to get the contents of the body tag:

```
function loader() {
    var typed = $('#i').val(); //get what user typed in
    $.get('script.php', { i: typed }, function(loaded) {
        alert($(loaded).find('body').html());
    });
}
```

Also note that if the `script.php` only echoes `1!!2` without a `<body>` tag it won't work.

Comment: This just displays `null`. Leaving off the `.html()` displays the same `[Object object]`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nathan G., no idea, instead of using alerts to debug your javascript code I would strongly recommend you [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/). It will provide you much more information about the AJAX request and eventually help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what console.log prints it is hard to say, but try these

```
alert($(dataloaded).find('body').html());
```

Or

```
alert($(dataloaded).find('body').text());
```

Comment: `.html` just displays `null`. `.text()` displays an empty dialog. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON type. I am not sure about whether your Jquery script correct or not but using JSON with a correct usage would solve problem. ie.:

```
function loader() {
    var typed = $('#i').val(); //get what user typed in
    $.get("script.php", {i: typed}, function(loaded) {dataloaded = loaded;},"json");
    alert($(dataloaded).find('body'))
}
```

And POST variable from script.php after encoding JSON. Use Php's json_encode() function. You need to create variable as an array. For example:

```
<?php 
$title = 'Hello World';
$content = 'Get well soon Japan!';
$arr=array('title'=>$title,'content'=>$content);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

And Jquery would be something like:

```
function loader() {
var typed = $('#i').val(); //get what user typed in
$.get("script.php", {i: typed}, function(loaded) {var dataloaded = loaded.title+" "+loaded.content;},"json");
$("body").html(dataloaded);
}
```

You may need to use Jquery's parseJson() functions on some situations. Don't think you will need here.

Comment: Well, I didn't tested Jquery script on my pc whether it is true cause editor not open and will sleep soon. But I believe that JSON type will solve the issue. And you should echo encoded array at your PHP file.

Comment: @Nathan G. I if I didn't understand wrong you want to write grabbed text inside body. Look at my update.

Comment: @Ahmet I don't want to show the retrieved text, I want to assign the part of it that represents the body of the page retrieved to a variable for processing.

Comment: Then change you get function like (based on my sample php script): `function(loaded) {var dataloaded = $.parseJson(loaded.title)+" "+$.parseJson(loaded.content);}` and use it your way: `alert($(dataloaded).find('body').html());`

Comment: And also it might be better to put a `var` before `dataloaded` on your get function.

Comment: Just if someones comes acroos this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423257/find-body-tag-in-an-ajax-html-response